# Node.js cannot require a .js file in the same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have a node-webkit project with a `main.js`. At the very top, I have

```
var updater = require("./updater.js");
```

and I have a file named `updater.js` in the same directory as `main.js`. When I run the app, I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './updater.js'
```

`updater.js` has one line in it:

```
module.exports = "Hello!";
```

I have no idea why it cannot require the file. I have seen another project do the same thing. I can `require` regular `npm` modules just fine from the same `main.js`.

Comment: Do you have read permission to `updater.js`?

Comment: And how did you start node? Did you start node in this directory directly by typing `node main.js`? If you used some helpers the `cwd` may have changed.

Comment: are you using `node main` in the directory that `main.js` is in, when it throws this error, or are you loading in `main.js` as a module in a different script?

Comment: Give it a try with var updater = require("./updater");

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is because, when you run you app (main.js) using node-webkit the root (working) directory is where the index.html is in, so './' refers to that directory not the one in which the file you requesting the module from is in.

You can easily solve this problem by using [resolve method in 'path' node module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) and provide the output from it to the require method in your working file

Simply do the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var updater = require( path.resolve( __dirname, "./updater.js" ) );
```

EDIT : info on global node object '__dirname' (and others) can by found [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

Comment: Plus 1 for the link to the doc

Comment: Is there a less verbose way of requiring a single file (without the need for 2 lines, path, path.resolve, __dirname, relative paths, etc.)?

Comment: While this solution definitely works, the './' (which I was missing) seems to actually work as one would expect now and the `path.resolve( __dirname...` isn't needed anymore